# Xcode 9.1 beta 2 100% CPU usage in Idle

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-usage

Fortunately, MapKit and SpriteKit work well in this beta, but I'm having another problem running Xcode.

I'm running MacOS Sierra on an Hackintosh with i5 7600k and even if Xcode 9 beta 2 is idle and the simulator is off, CPU usage is constant to 100%.

Is there anybody who knows how to fix this or it is another Xcode bug? They'll never end!